# How does computers sync the data and time while have no electricity?

Tags: sync, battery, clock

How computers sync the data and time, While computer has isn't connected to any charge/electricity source?
For example I set date and time on Windows and then I Shutted-down whole system,
Pluged-out the charge cable And Removed the battery(My battery isn't working [yet]),
after a while(Like a Month or a Year) I Pluged-in The Charger Soket, Placed Battery back and Started-up,
Then date and time loaded and showed the correct date and time.

- **How this happened?**

Comment: "How does computers sync the data and time while computer has no electricity?" - **This is not possible.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A computer requires a source of an extremely small amount of electrical energy to keep the time. If *all* of the sources of energy are removed from the system, or run out of energy, the computer cannot keep time.

A conventional desktop computer has the following sources of energy.

- The plug that supplies primary power to the Power Supply Unit (PSU)
- A small, non-rechargeable, "cell battery" with a tiny amount of stored energy that, while very small, is enough to help the motherboard keep the time. (I'm purposefully avoiding a technical description of *how* it keeps time).

A laptop adds one more source of energy:

- The rechargeable battery that has enough energy to power the whole laptop for several hours. This is a very large and usually noticeable battery on most laptop models (because of its physical size and weight, and often protruding outside the main chassis).

Once the computer has been powered on and is running from one of the primary sources of energy, it can keep time easily by continuously drawing from that power source.

Once the computer is powered down and the primary power sources are no longer being used (I'm including a laptop's main battery in the term "primary power source" here), it only has the small cell battery on the motherboard as a backup power source to keep the time.

However, that battery has a limited amount of energy in it, and will eventually run dry. When that happens, each time you power off the computer, it will "forget" the time.

Most batteries of this type are designed to last for around 5 to 15 years, though for extremely special use cases like space probes, satellites or ground-based systems designed to run unattended for extremely long periods of time, the cell battery might be specially engineered to last much longer, or it may be a rechargeable battery that periodically refills itself from the primary power source. Or it might not be a battery at all. But these are very special case uses.

Answer (score 0):

Allquixotic's answer is correct, and it is certainly the primary way the system keeps track of time while powered off. Most modern operating systems (probably all, but I'm not positive) also keep the time updated from time servers on the Internet. If the computer can connect to the Internet, it will update the time very quickly, even if the motherboard battery dies. Depending on how things are configured, this update can occur before any click is displayed to the user.

Comment: My experience tells me otherwise. Timeserver syncs are based on a few things, a service, scheduled tasks and internet connectivitiy. Given that all 3 are required to be active at the same time for the time to update, it is far more likely the user would see their clock before all 3 conditions are met, and of course when they are met, it is not likely to be happening instantly thereafter.